# how many index per database table?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

How many indexes is preferred for one table in MySQL??

I have a `company` table where I search mostly for `ID`, `state`, and `category`.

Comment: What kinds of queries will you be running on this table? insert, upate, select, delete?

Comment: More detail would help. We have to guess that ID is probably your primary key, rather than a composite of ID and category (which is entirely possible). If you post the schema, we'd have a better idea.

Comment: You search "FOR" id,state,cat or you search "BY" them. To me, "FOR" means they are in the select list. e.g. I search FOR songs BY artist. BY is in the where clause.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no one single answer for this question: create as many indexes are required to make your queries fast enough, and no more.

You have to trade off various things when deciding what to index:

- The more indexes you have, the slower inserts and updates will be (because they need to update all of the indexes)
- Queries over tables without an appropriate index *can* be very slow, if the database has to do a table scan
- Some columns do not require indexes (for example, a 'gender' column where the only possible value is "M" or "F")

For your particular scenario, it seems like three indexes, one on ID (if this is the primary key, then it already has an implicit index), one on state and one on category, would suffice.

Comment: I doubt State or Category would be useful on their own. But without cardinality there's no way to know. If they do business in all 50 (53) states then perhaps you get to 1-5% of the table via that indexes, but if its a regional business that does business primarily in 10 states, then it probably will not have a low enough clustering factor to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "preferred" number of indexes, it all depends on your queries.  In your example, you would need no more than 3 indexes, one for ID, one for state, and one for category.